# Casting Preference for int float vs double

Tags: java, casting, overloading

Here is my code simple overloading code in java.

```
public class Test {
    static void test(float x){
        System.out.print("float");
    }

    static void test(double x){
        System.out.print("double");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        test(99.9);
        test(99.9f);
        test(99);
    }
}
```

the ans is

```
double
float
float
```

I know why it is giving answer for first and second call but for third it is calling float .Why? Please share answer with some knowlegebale link if you have.

Comment: Well, this clearly shows that java implicitly converts integer values to floats.

Comment: @gooroo7 Did you read the question? The OP already knows that, he is asking *why* it prefers `float` to `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JLS [§15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) specifies the rules for selecting the most appropriate method. The relevant parts are (bold highlight by me):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the **most *specific method* is chosen**.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

> A type S is *more specific* than a type T for *any* expression if S <: T ([§4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10)).

JLS [§4.10.1. Subtyping among Primitive Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1) defines:

> The following rules define the direct supertype relation among the primitive types:
>
> - `double` ><sub>1</sub> `float`
> - `float` ><sub>1</sub> `long`
> - `long` ><sub>1</sub> `int`
> - `int` ><sub>1</sub> `char`
> - `int` ><sub>1</sub> `short`
> - `short` ><sub>1</sub> `byte`

Or chaining them along, ignoring `char`, with the **right-most being the most *specific***:

`double` > `float` > `long` > `int` > `short` > `byte`

So, as you can see, **an `int` value, or even a `long` value, will choose a `float` parameter over a `double` parameter**, when though, as JLS [§5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) says it:

> A widening primitive conversion from `int` to `float`, or from `long` to `float`, or from `long` to `double`, may result in *loss of precision* - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value.

Answer (score 1):

JLS 5.1.2 covers widening rules https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

> int to long, float, or double

Note: float is before double and if you had a method which took a `long` it would be chosen.

This is despite the fact that an int can lose precision converting to a float but not to a double.

Comment: Although the referenced JLS section *happens* to list the types in that order, it doesn't actually define that the listed order is relevant to method selection. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43557093/5221149) for *actual* rules of method selection relevant to this question.